# Spring JDBCTemplate NULL check

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbctemplate

I am trying to fetch a summation of values from my mysql database table using Spring JDBCTemplate.

I get a null pointer exception when there is no any relevant data in the table for a particular query. 
This is my code;

```
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT SUM(paid_value) FROM all_delay_payments_breakdown WHERE customer_order_id = '"+customerOrderId+"' AND installment_no = '"+i+"'";

        partialTot = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Double.class);
        tot = tot + partialTot ;


    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception: While calculation partial tot for customer order id :"+customerOrderId+" and instlmnt nmbr : "+i+" = "+e);
    }
```

I need to check for the value returned by the query, and then if it is null, add 0 to the `tot`, otherwise add the value returned by the query execution to the variable `tot`.

But I cannot check whether the returned value is null after this code snippet.

```
partialTot = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Double.class);
```

the code will not go forward , if the returned value is null. (since the query execution code throws an null pointer exception, hence the execution goes directly in to the `catch` clause)

So how can I do this? I am looking for something like this

```
if(partialTot == null ){
    tot = tot + 0;
}else{
    tot = tot+ partialTot;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`, it will return `0` if `sum` returns `null`:

```
select coalesce(sum(paid_value), 0) from <...>
```